# Toast and AlarmManager works fine actually when I run but does't repeat after I boot my device?

Tags: android

```
MainActivity
```

Here I called MyService.java who contains the AlarmManager code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MyService.class));}}
```

**Service Class**

Here I wrote the AlarmManager who repeat my Toast every second

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand (Intent intent,int flags ,int startid) {

    // Toast.makeText(this , " SErvic " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   Intent i = new Intent(this, MyReceiver.class);
  i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 20000, pi);

return 0;
}


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}}
```

**Receiver Class**

In MyReceiver.java I put my Toast message to show

```
public void onReceive(Context context , Intent intent ){

    Toast.makeText(context , "Service Started" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   //  Intent i = new Intent(context,MyService.class);
    // context.startService(i);
}}
```

***Manifest

android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>***

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

<application

    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

         <receiver android:name=".MyReceiver"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.permission.BOOT_COMPLETED">

            </action>
        </intent-filter>

        </receiver>


    <service android:name=".MyService"
        android:enabled="true"/>

</application>
```

Comment: Alarms don't survive rebooting. You need to set it again when your Receiver gets the `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast. Also, remove the `permission` attribute from the `<receiver>` element.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to receive BOOT COMPLETED intent.

Create a receiver class and add this line `<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"` to its intent-filter.

Inside the onReceive method of that class, simply start your service.

Example

```
public class MyBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
        startService(MyService);
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add `<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"` to the intent-filter of `MyBootReceiver`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON` to your `intent-filter`